# Access oly for admins

Tags: laravel, api, jwt, laravel-sanctum

I want to make middleware that allows access only for admins. In Sanctum is a little bit complicated because if I try (in middleware) display that

```
dd(Auth::user())
```

it returns null. But this same code in api.php displays the user's detail. So I know that I can write this code (I use httponly cookie) but it's ugly, complicated and I don't sure that it's safe.

```
$cookie = $request->cookie('user');
$explodeFields = explode(',', $cookie);
$role = explode(':', $explodeFields[4])[1];
dd($role);
```

User table has a column "role" and then is the role of user, for example, "admin". In middleware I want to check that user is an admin and if he is, allow access. How do that?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you add some kind of user level as a column on the user model. If you only want admins and non-admins you could have a boolean called is_admin. Then you can create a middleware that looks something like this:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (Auth::user()->is_admin == true) {
         return $next($request);
    }

    return abort(404);
}
```

Apply this middleware to the routes that you want to restrict to admins only.

Comment: I understand your idea but it's impossible because like I said before in middleware `Auth::user()` returns `null`. All the time we talk about Sanctum and using api.php, not web.php. In api.php I can return `Auth::user()`.